# R - levels are annoyingly messing things up, simple issue

Tags: r, levels

I have a variable in R that looks like so

```
> q
[1] 0.4231
Levels: 0.4231
```

I want to get rid of that crazy levels thing. I just want the value. How do I do this. I tried

```
> as.numeric(q)
[1] 1
```

Which doesn't work.

For example, I want to do some simple arithmetic, such as `q+1`, which I currently cannot do

```
> q+1
[1] NA
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(q, 1) : + not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: Stupid question: why is it a factor in the first place? Looks like you're reading something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have forgotten to do some simple steps.
First, if you want to convert q to numeric, `as.numeric(q)` only returns q as if it is numeric, without converting q itself to numeric. Second, you cannot go directly from a factor to a numeric; you need to convert it to character, and then numeric.

This is what I tried below:

I reproduced your example:

```
q<-as.factor(0.423)
q
[1] 0.423
Levels: 0.423
as.numeric(q)
[1] 1
q+1
[1] NA
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(q, 1) : + not meaningful for factors
```

To show you that you cannot change a factor directly to numeric: see how q+1 is not eu

```
q<-as.numeric(q)
q+1
[1] 2
```

Finally, this is the correct way to convert a factor q to a numeric string:

```
q<-as.numeric(as.character((q)))
q+1
[1] 1.423
```